# Install Ubuntu 17.04 on UEFI machine

Tags: system-installation

I recently bought a new laptop (HP ba054nl) that has a UEFI system. I tried to install Linux. But all distros that I've tried lock up at the boot process and the installation won't start. I've disabled fast startup, secure boot and I've used Rufus for GPT installation on my USB drive. But it won't start. What can I do, what bios settings can I change to fix this?

Comment: Try using Rufus in MBR mode as a DD image as opposed to the ISO mode.

Comment: I would recommend switching to MBR mode as @FireFaced suggested. This is called CSM or legacy mode on many systems and is usually under the same section as the hard drive settings are in. Anyways, it is important to note that changing this setting will prevent Windows (or any other OS) from booting properly until the mode is switched back to its original setting. For this reason, this option is not viable for dual-boot systems and I would only recommend trying it on a Linux-only system.

Comment: I've tried the DD option, but the system still lock up at the boot screen. I've also used the MBR partition in Rufus, both for BIOS and UEFI.

Comment: What do you mean by it "locking up"?